Minimum Number of Squares to Color
This is the December 23rd puzzle from Matthew Scroggs' annual puzzle advent calendar. It has me stumped, so I'm looking for a hint on how to proceed. The text of the puzzle is below:

In a grid of squares, each square is friendly with itself and friendly with every square that is horizontally, vertically, or diagonally adjacent to it (and is not friendly with any other squares). In a $5\times5$ grid, it is possible to colour $8$ squares so that every square is friendly with at least two coloured squares:



It is not possible to do this by colouring fewer than $8$ squares.
What is the fewest number of squares that need to be coloured in a $23\times23$ grid so that every square is friendly with at least two coloured squares?

My usual plan for puzzles like this is to start small and look for a pattern.
In a $1\times1$ grid it is impossible for the lone square to be "friendly" with $2$ squares.
In a $2\times2$ grid, coloring any $2$ squares will do the job.
In a $3\times3$ grid, coloring the middle row or column of $3$ squares works and seems to be the minimal solution.
In a $4\times4$ grid, I think the minimal solution is $8$ squares (like the $5\times5$ grid). That's because no two corners have any common neighbors and each needs two colored neighbors. Coloring the $8$ squares along the two diagonals works, for example.
So here's where I am stuck, because I haven't been able to "scale up".
The one theory I have (which is likely wrong):

 I note that all the minimal solutions so far have been Fibonacci Numbers, which has been a hallmark of this advent calendar in past years. Since $4\times4$ and $5\times5$ have the same solution, it may be that $(2n)\times(2n)$ and $(2n+1)\times(2n+1)$ continue to have the same solution? Following the Fibonacci pattern, this would lead to a final answer of $610$ colored squares in the $23\times23$ grid. This is in line with the contest rules that each day must have a $3$ digit answer.

I'm not necessarily looking for a full answer to this. Just hints on how to identify the pattern and move up to larger grids.

My conjectured answer can't be right because $23\times23$ grid only has $529$ total squares. Oops!

I also don't think the Fibonacci pattern holds. The $6 \times 6$ grid can be done with 10 coloured squares, the second and fifth columns almost completely coloured, with the fourth cells left out.

This is part of an ongoing contest. Part of the rules are: Ten randomly selected people who solve all the puzzles, open the warehouse, and fill in the entry form behind the door on the 25th will win prizes!
…
The winners will be randomly chosen from all those who submit the entry form before the end of 2024. Each day's puzzle (and the entry form on Christmas Day) will be available from 5:00am GMT. But as the winners will be selected randomly, there's no need to get up at 5am on Christmas Day to enter!

I would begin from the observation that in the 3x3 block centred on any square (which, if the square is at the edge, may have fewer than 9 actual squares in it) there must be at least two coloured squares.
(This is deliberately not a complete answer, because OP specifically says "I'm not necessarily looking for a full answer to this" and after all this is an ongoing contest of sorts. I am pretty sure Matthew Scroggs will not be upset by this amount of online discussion. But if you, yes you, are reading this and happen to be Matthew Scroggs, do please comment and tell me if I'm wrong!)

I'm not sure how to proceed from this observation. There is so much overlap among all the $3\times3$ blocks. Two different blocks could share either 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 6 squares (not even considering blocks at the edge of the grid).

As you realized - overlaps are not good. So, just don't overlap. I'm afraid that further hint will ruin the fun for you.

For a fixed $n\times n$ grid, you can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_{ij}$ indicate whether cell $(i,j)$ is colored.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij}$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=i-1}^{i+1} \sum_{c=j-1}^{j+1} x_{rc} &\ge 2 &&\text{for all $(i,j)\in \{1,\dots,n\} \times \{1,\dots,n\}$}
\end{align}
Here are the resulting minimum values for $n \in \{2,\dots,23\}$:

 2 3 8 8 10 18 18 21 32 32 36 50 50 55 72 72 78 98 98 105 128 128

In fact, the linear programming relaxation yields these same minimum values, and the dual variables provide a short certificate of optimality.
It appears that $(3n+1)\times(3n+1)$ and $(3n+2)\times(3n+2)$ yield the same minimum, as you observed for $4\times4$ and $5\times5$.
Here are two hints for $23\times23$:

You can obtain the minimum value by never having more than two adjacent ones in a connected component.
$2m^2$


Clearly not a full answer, just a lower bound:
It's obvious that for large n, an nxn grid requires at least $\frac{2n^2}{9}$ coloured squares - each square has 9 neighbours, and each requires 2 neighbouring coloured squares.  We can make a slight improvement to this by noticing that at least 4 coloured squares must be on the edge (one per corner), and there are 3 "missing" squares for each of those, so that brings us to a lower bound of $\frac{2n^2+12}{9}$.
